# python - rename files with 001,002 etc

Tags: python

I am working on a code that will encode my files according to the filename. If the file is named DOG, CAT, the file should be renamed to DEL/DBD plus date and number (001,002). The problem is that if I have several CAT files, I get an error as the code does not increment the number. Also, the numeration should be separate for each file type (so CAT 001, 002 and DOG 001, 002).

I've tried to increase the counter by one every time I get the FileNameError exception, but it does not seem to work. Could you please help me out?

```
import os
from datetime import date

def rename_files():
    path = 'U:\get_filename'
    cur_day = str(date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    counter =+ 1
    stamp_2 = "{} 00{}.pdf".format(cur_day,str(counter))

    del01 = 'DEL ' + stamp_2
    dbd02 = 'DBD ' + stamp_2
    cgf01 = 'CGF ' + stamp_2
    cle01 = 'CLE ' + stamp_2
    dmm01 = 'DMM ' + stamp_2
    dqt01 = 'DQT ' + stamp_2
    sri01 = 'SRI ' + stamp_2
    cal01 = 'CAL ' + stamp_2



    for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f: 
            counter +=1
            try:
                        if 'DOG' in file:
                            os.rename(file, del01)
                        elif 'CAT' in file:
                            os.rename(file, dbd02)
                        elif 'BIRD' in file:
                            os.rename(file, cgf01)
                        elif 'FISH' in file:
                            os.rename(file, cle01)
                        elif 'INSECT' in file:
                            os.rename(file, dmm01)
                        elif 'CAR' in file:
                            os.rename(file, dqt01)
                        elif 'BIKE' in file:
                            os.rename(file, sri01)
                        elif 'SCOOTER' in file:
                            os.rename(file, cal01)
            except: 
                counter +=1

rename_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from datetime import date

names = {
    "DEL": 1,
    "DBD": 1,
    "CGF": 1,
    "CLE": 1,
    "DMM": 1,
    "DQT": 1,
    "SRI": 1,
    "CAL": 1,
}
cur_day = str(date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"))


def rename(source, name):
    prefix = "{} {0:03d}.pdf".format(cur_day, names[name])
    try:
        os.rename(source, "{} {}".format(name, prefix))
        names[name] += 1
    except:
        pass

def rename_files():
    path = "U:\get_filename"

    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if "DOG" in file:
                rename(file, "DEL")
            elif "CAT" in file:
                rename(file, "DBD")
            elif "BIRD" in file:
                rename(file, "CGF")
            elif "FISH" in file:
                rename(file, "CLE")
            elif "INSECT" in file:
                rename(file, "DMM")
            elif "CAR" in file:
                rename(file, "DQT")
            elif "BIKE" in file:
                rename(file, "SRI")
            elif "SCOOTER" in file:
                rename(file, "CAL")

rename_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, thanks for help. Though it's not quite perfect yet, when I run the rename function, I get a - TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

cur_day = str(date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"))

def main():

    print("Current Working Directory " , os.getcwd())
    os.chdir(r'U:\\get_filename')

    i = 1
    j = 1
    k = 1
    l = 1
    m = 1
    n = 1
    o = 1
    p = 1
    q = 1
    r = 1

    path = r'U:\get_filename'
    for filename in os.listdir(r'U:\get_filename'):
        my_dest = 'CLE ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(i) + ".pdf"
        my_dest2 = 'DBD ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(j) + ".pdf"
        my_dest3 = 'CGF ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(k) + ".pdf"
        my_dest4 = 'CLE ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(l) + ".pdf"
        my_dest5 = 'DMM ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(m) + ".pdf"
        my_dest6 = 'DQT ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(n) + ".pdf"
        my_dest7 = 'SRI ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(o) + ".pdf"
        my_dest8 = 'CAL ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(p) + ".pdf"
        my_dest9 = 'BIL ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(q) + ".pdf"
        my_dest10 = 'DEL ' + cur_day + ' 00' + str(r) + ".pdf"
        my_source = path + filename
        if 'Jerry' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest)
            i +=1
        elif 'Bob' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest2)
            j +=1
        elif 'Sara' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest3)
            k +=1
        elif 'Greg' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest4)
            l +=1
        elif 'Annie' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest5)
            m +=1
        elif 'Beth' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest6)
            n +=1
        elif 'Claire' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest7)
            o +=1
        elif 'Johnny' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest8)
            p +=1
        elif 'Bob' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest9)
            q +=1
        elif 'Jimbo' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, my_dest10)
            r +=1

def exp_names():
    list_files = os.listdir(r'U:\\get_filename')
    list_2 = [x.strip('.pdf') for x in list_files]
    list_2 = pd.DataFrame(list_2)
    list_3 = list_2[list_2[0] != 'iles.xlsx']
    list_3.to_excel(r'U:\get_filename\\files.xlsx', header = False, index = False)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    exp_names()
```

Comment: This is the final version - the result is working fine, though I'm sure it could be achieved with less variables.